# How to Put Buttons on VideoView in Different Places?

Tags: android

How to Put Buttons on VideoView and Change the Video URL on the Click Event of The Buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use Framelayout and add VideoView & Button to the layout. Since FrameLayout allows children views to overlay, you can have a visible button on VideoView.
2. Implement onClick() listener to listen to the button press event.

Do you need code for the same ?